# how to make a method generic in java such that it work with any object?

Tags: java, generics

i have below model classes for example

```
class A{}
class B{}
```

Main or calling class

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
  String aJson = "/tmp/a.json";
  List<A> aList = readAJsonAsList(aJson);
  String bJson = "/tmp/b.json";
  List<B> bList = readBJsonAsList(bJson);
}
```

Now I am reading json files analogous to models A and B using jackson.

```
// method for A
    private static List<A> readAJsonAsList(String jsonAFile) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper omA = new ObjectMapper();
        List<A> aList = omA.readValue(new File(jsonAFile), new TypeReference<ArrayList<A>>() {
        });
        return aList;
    }
    
// method for B
    private static List<B> readBJsonAsList(String jsonBFile) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper omB = new ObjectMapper();
        List<B> bList = omB.readValue(new File(jsonBFile), new TypeReference<ArrayList<B>>() {
        });
        return bList;
    }
```

how can I make one generic java method from above two methods?

Note:
I have tried below but does not work

```
private static <T> List<T> readJsonAsList(String jsonFile) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<T> list = objectMapper.readValue(new File(jsonFile), new TypeReference<ArrayList<T>>() {
    });
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the element type as method parameter and use [TypeFactory](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeFactory.html), more precisely [TypeFactory.constructCollectionType(collectionClass, elementClass)](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeFactory.html#constructCollectionType(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class)) to build the `JavaType` dynamically at runtime.

Additionally i would suggest to use `InputStream` as the parameter, it's more generic and you can use the method with basically anything (file streams, you can convert text to streams, other streams).

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("path-to-file")) {
      List<A> aList = readAsList(stream, A.class);
      System.out.println(aList);
    } catch (IOException exc) {
      exc.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static <T> List<T> readAsList(InputStream inputStream, Class<T> elementType) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TypeFactory factory = TypeFactory.defaultInstance();
    return mapper.readValue(inputStream, factory.constructCollectionType(List.class, elementType));
  }

  private static class A {
  }

  private static class B {
  }
}
```